# Toggling the rendering of Text(script) on GetKeyDown (Unity 4.6)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a main menu, I've got everything working besides the help section.

The idea is, the user presses H to display help information, then pressing H again removes it from the screen. I'm not after destroying it as that would then mean it wouldn't return unless the game is reloaded?

I've tried different code but it's not working, any help would be appreciated!

I've spent 30 minutes adding and taking away from it, this is what I'm currently left with, it's by no means perfect but hopefully it'll help someone understand what I'm trying to do. As it stands, it logs "H pressed" but not "Renderer enabled".

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.H))
        Debug.Log ("H pressed");
        renderer.enabled = true;
        Debug.Log ("Renderer enabled");

}
```

Comment: A simple way is set the object inactive either through another script or it's own script (but you will want to set it active later so I suggest having a manager script) by using "gameobject.SetActive(false);"

Comment: How would I link it to the actual text? I feel stupid but this has been stumping me for far too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is missing brackets, so only one line executes when it is its turn.

If you are using a GUIText then you can simply add a string to the text component.

```
rendered.enabled = !rendered.enabled;
```